# How to search nextjs13 in layout

Tags: javascript, next.js

I use next js 13 build a project,I have a layout

```
"use client";

import PageProgress from "@/components/PageProgress";
import { headSearchStore, useStore2 } from "_store/headSearch";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function WebLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const { key, setKey } = headSearchStore();
  const searchKey = () => {
   
  };
  return (
    <>
      <header>
 <form>
<input
                    type="search"
                    id="search"
                    value={key}
                    onChange={(e) => setKey(e.target.value)}
                    className="border-none   block w-full p-2 pl-10 focus:outline-none  text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50"
                    placeholder="Search"
                  />
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={searchKey}
                    className="absolute top-0 right-0 p-2.5 h-full  font-medium text-white bg-gray-600 rounded-r-lg border border-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-600   focus:outline-none "
                  >
 </form>
</header>
{children}
 </>
  );
```

I want to realize that after inputting content in the layout text box, click the button to search and change the data in the data table of the page. I tried to use the useRouter component in the layout, but unfortunately, an error was reported and it was not allowed to be used with the layout. Use useRouter.push in layout. Do I have any other solutions? Thank you.

I want to realize that after inputting content in the layout text box, click the button to search and change the data in the data table of the page. I tried to use the useRouter component in the layout, but unfortunately, an error was reported and it was not allowed to be used with the layout. Use useRouter.push in layout. Do I have any other solutions? Thank you.